# update instant message in conversation activity - Android

Tags: android-studio, retrofit2, instant-messaging

I am building an instant messaging feature in my app using retrofit 2.0,php and mysql. But i do not know how to show and update the messages received and send in the recyclerview.

conversation Activity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_conversation);

        dp=findViewById(R.id.conversationUser);
        back=findViewById(R.id.goBackFromCoversation);
        name=findViewById(R.id.conversationUserName);
        activeStatus=findViewById(R.id.conversationUserSeen);
        shareTitle=findViewById(R.id.conversationStatusTitle);
        typeMessage=findViewById(R.id.typeMessage);
        attach=findViewById(R.id.attachFiles);
        send=findViewById(R.id.sendMessage);
        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.conversationRv);
        toolbar=findViewById(R.id.converationToolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        if (SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).contains("keyid")) {
            id = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getUser().getId();
            Toast.makeText(this, "user id is " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "no id found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        getUserId= getIntent().getIntExtra("userId",0);
        getUserName=getIntent().getStringExtra("userName");
        getUserDp=getIntent().getStringExtra("dpUrl");
        chatType=getIntent().getIntExtra("chatType",0);

        if(getUserDp==null){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"user dp is null, value is "+getUserDp,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            loadDp(getUserDp);
        }

        name.setText(getUserName);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        ((LinearLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);

        fetchConversation(id,getUserId);

        cla=new ConversationAdapter(this,conversation);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(cla);

        back.setOnClickListener(this);
        name.setOnClickListener(this);
        attach.setOnClickListener(this);
        send.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){

            case R.id.goBackFromCoversation:
                finish();
                break;
            case R.id.conversationUserName:
                Intent intent= new Intent(ConversationActivity.this,ViewProfileActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("userId",getUserId);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.attachFiles:
                break;
            case R.id.sendMessage:
                getTextMessage=typeMessage.getText().toString();
                messageType=0;
                sendMessage(chatType,id,getUserId,messageType,getTextMessage);
                onCreate(null);
                break;

        }
    }

    private void fetchConversation(int id, int getUserId) {

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

        Retrofit retrofi = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://192.168.56.110/app2/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();
        RetrofitApi service = retrofi.create(RetrofitApi.class);
        Call<Message> call = service.getMessages(id,getUserId);

      /*  Call<Message> call = RetrofitClient
                .getmInstance()
                .getApi()
                .getMessages(id, Integer.parseInt(getUserId));*/

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Message>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Message> call, Response<Message> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    if (response.body() != null) {
                        Message sr = response.body();
                        int count=sr.getConversation().toArray().length;
                        if(sr.getSuccess()==1){
                            for(int i=0;i<sr.getConversation().toArray().length;i++){

                                messageId=sr.getConversation().get(i).getMessageId();
                                fromId=sr.getConversation().get(i).getSenderId();
                                toId=sr.getConversation().get(i).getReceiverId();
                                type=sr.getConversation().get(i).getType();
                                timeSent=sr.getConversation().get(i).getTime_sent();
                                message=sr.getConversation().get(i).getMessage();
                                Conversation c=new Conversation(messageId,fromId,toId,type,message,timeSent);
                                conversation.add(c);
                                cla.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }else{
                            Log.v(TAG,"success is not 1");
                        }

                    } else {
                        Log.v(TAG, "fetchConvo, response is null ");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "resposne is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.v(TAG, "fetchConvo, Something went wrong");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong- ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Message> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.v(TAG, "fetchConvo, response is" + t.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failure, response is- " + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.v(TAG, "fetchConvo, Failed, cause is " + t.getCause());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed, cause is - " + t.getCause(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }

    private void loadDp(String getUserDp) {

        String[] parts= getUserDp.split("htdocs");
        String newString="http://192.168.56.110"+ parts[1];
        Log.e(TAG, newString );

            GlideApp.with(this).
                    load(newString)
                    .diskCacheStrategy( DiskCacheStrategy.ALL )
                    .into(dp);

    }



    private void sendMessage(int chat,int id, int getUserId, int messageType, String getTextMessage) {

        Log.v(TAG,"id is"+ id);
        Log.v(TAG,"userId is"+ getUserId);
        Log.v(TAG,"type is"+ messageType);
        Log.v(TAG,"message is"+getTextMessage);

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

        Retrofit retrofi = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://192.168.56.110/app2/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();
        RetrofitApi service = retrofi.create(RetrofitApi.class);
        Call<com.example.user.myapplication.Model.Response> call = service.saveMessages(id,getUserId,getTextMessage,messageType);

    /*    Call<com.example.user.myapplication.Model.Response> call = RetrofitClient
                .getmInstance()
                .getApi()
                .saveMessages(id,getUserId,getTextMessage,messageType);*/

        call.enqueue(new Callback<com.example.user.myapplication.Model.Response>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<com.example.user.myapplication.Model.Response> call, Response<com.example.user.myapplication.Model.Response> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    if (response.body() != null) {
                        com.example.user.myapplication.Model.Response sr = response.body();
                        if(sr.getSuccess()==1){
                            Log.v(TAG,"Response is successful");
                        }
                       } else {
                        Log.v(TAG, "saveMessage, response is null ");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "resposne is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                   } else {
                    Log.v(TAG, "saveMessage, Something went wrong");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong- ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<com.example.user.myapplication.Model.Response> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.v(TAG, "saveMessage, response is" + t.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failure, response is- " + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.v(TAG, "saveMessage, Failed, cause is " + t.getCause());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed, cause is - " + t.getCause(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }
```

Conversation Adapter

```
public class ConversationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ConversationAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = "ChatListAdapter";
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Conversation> conversation= new ArrayList<>();
    private int id;

    public ConversationAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Conversation> conversation) {
        this.context = context;
        this.conversation = conversation;
    }



    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ConversationAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_message, viewGroup, false);
        ConversationAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = new ConversationAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {


        if (SharedPrefManager.getInstance(context).contains("keyid")) {
            id = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(context).getUser().getId();
            Toast.makeText(context, "user id is " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "no id found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

       if(Integer.parseInt(conversation.get(i).getSenderId())==id){
            viewHolder.messageSent.setText(conversation.get(i).getMessage());
            viewHolder.messaegReceievd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       }else{
           viewHolder.messaegReceievd.setText(conversation.get(i).getMessage());
           viewHolder.messageSent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       }

       if(i==conversation.toArray().length-1) {
           viewHolder.messageTime.setText(conversation.get(conversation.toArray().length- 1).getTime_sent());
       }else{
           viewHolder.messageTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return conversation.toArray().length;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        BubbleTextView messageSent,messaegReceievd;
        TextView messageTime;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Log.v(TAG, "ViewHolder, setting view in variables");

            messageSent=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textMessageSent);
            messaegReceievd=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textMessageReceived);
            messageTime=itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageSentTime);

        }
    }


}
```

Whenever i send message and tries to reload the activity to show the messages received or send i start activity again and have to make network request once again which i think will take much time when real user will use it. So, therefore i want to implement something else to make it instant messaging activity.

Any help would be appreciated Thanks in advance